# While trying to open analysis server properties getting error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssas-2012

[Image for error with analysis services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKtaf.png)

Can anyone know about the following error which is happening while trying to open analysis server properties..

cannot show requested dialog.(sqlmgmt)
Additional information:
the type initializer for
'Microsoft.analysisservices.managementdialogs.server propertieslanguagepanel' threw an exception.(Microsoft.Analysisservices.ssmsmanagementdialogs)
Item has already been added. key in dictionary:'4096'(mscorlib)

Comment: Can anyone know about this issue.. I can't able to open properties window..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what help me to get properties window running was install SP3 of sql server 2012.

[sp3 sql server 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49996)

after that it worked for me.

I hope it help someone else.

Comment: Thank you Destined. I will also try.

Comment: try using the repair option on SQL Server installer, that worked for my colleague.